# Square root of $-I_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to get all matrices $N \in M_2(\mathbb R)$ such that $N^2 = -I_2$.

To start with, I know that 
$N_0=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ works, and we can prove that every matrices $N$ that are similar to $N_0$ work.

$i.e.$ Let $N \in M_2(\mathbb R)$ if $\exists P \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$ such that $N = PN_0P^{-1}$, then $N^2 = -I_2$.

My question is, is the converse true?

Are all matrices $N \in M_2(\mathbb R)$ such that $N^2 = -I_2$ similar to $N_0$?

Comment: Do you know about diagonalization already ?

Comment: Use Jordan normal form at the fact that $-1$ is central.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, write $A \sim B$ if $A$ and $B$ are similar in $\mathbb{C}$.

Assume that $N \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $N^2 + I_2 = 0$. Then the minimal polynomial of $N$ is $X^2+1$ and this factors into distinct linear factors in $\mathbb{C}$. So $N$ is diagonalizable in $\mathbb{C}$ with eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$, i.e., $N \sim \operatorname{diag}(i, -i) $ in $\mathbb{C}$. By the same reason, $N_0 \sim \operatorname{diag}(i, -i)$ and hence $N \sim N_0$. Then the desired claim follows from the following proposition.

> **Proposition.** Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose that $A \sim B$. Then $A$ and $B$ are similar in $\mathbb{R}$.

*Proof.* Choose $P \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A = PBP^{-1}$. Write $P = Q+iR$ for $Q, R \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and define $P_z = Q + zR$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

1. Since $AQ = QB$ and $AR = RB$, we have $AP_z = P_z B$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$,
2. $\det(P_i) = \det(P) \neq 0$, hence $\det(P_z)$ is a non-zero polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[z]$.

So we can find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P_x$ is invertible. Then $P_x \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $A = P_x BP_x^{-1}$, hence $A$ and $B$ are similar in $\mathbb{R}$ as required. $\Box$

Comment: You didn't have to prove your proposition, which is a pretty classical exercise but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very hard to find all matrices $N \in M_2(\Bbb R)$ such that

$N^2 = -I; \tag 1$

for let

$N = \begin{bmatrix} n_{11} & n_{12} \\ n_{21} & n_{22}\end{bmatrix}; \tag 2$

then

$\begin{bmatrix} n_{11}^2 + n_{12}n_{21} & n_{11}n_{12} + n_{12} n_{22} \\ n_{21}n_{11} +  n_{22} n_{21} & n_{21}n_{12} + n_{22}^2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} n_{11} & n_{12} \\ n_{21} & n_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} n_{11} & n_{12} \\ n_{21} & n_{22}\end{bmatrix} = N^2 = -I; \tag 3$

therefore,

$n_{11}^2 + n_{12}n_{21} = n_{21}n_{12} + n_{22}^2 = -1, \tag 4$

$(n_{11} + n_{22})n_{12} = (n_{11} +  n_{22})n_{21} = 0; \tag 5$

we see from this equation that

$\text{Tr}(N) = n_{11} + n_{22} \tag 6$

is a determinative, classifying factor; if

$\text{Tr}(N) \ne 0, \tag 7$

then from (5),

$n_{21} = n_{12} = 0, \tag 8$

whence from (4),

$n_{11}^2 = n_{22}^2 = -1; \tag 9$

clearly there are no real solutions in this case (7); thus we take

$\text{Tr}(N) = 0, \tag 8$

and see that

$-n_{22} = n_{11} = \alpha \in \Bbb R; \tag 9$

now from (4),

$n_{12}n_{21} \ne 0, \tag{10}$

implying

$n_{12} \ne 0 \ne n_{21}; \tag{11}$

thus we may write

$n_{21} = -\dfrac{1 + \alpha^2}{n_{12}}; \tag{12}$

if we set

$n_{12} = \beta \ne 0, \tag{13}$

then we may write

$n_{21} = -\dfrac{1 + \alpha^2}{\beta}; \tag{14}$

taken together, (9)-(14) provide a parameterized family of $2 \times 2$ matrices

$N(\alpha, \beta) = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ -\dfrac{1 + \alpha^2}{\beta} & -\alpha \end{bmatrix} \tag{15}$

such that

$N^2(\alpha, \beta) = -I. \tag{16}$

It is easy to see that the set of admissible parameters is characterized by

$\alpha \in \Bbb R, \; 0 \ne \beta \in \Bbb R. \tag{17}$

Careful scrutiny of the above argument reveals that we have in fact demonstrated that *every* matrix in $M_2(\Bbb R)$ satisfying (1) is of the form (15); therefore our parametric representation (15) is complete.

Since any $2 \times 2$ real matrix satisfting (1) is of the form (15), and we see that

$\text{Tr}(N(\alpha, \beta)) = \alpha + (-\alpha) = 0, \tag{18}$

and

$\det(N(\alpha, \beta)) = -\alpha^2 + \beta \dfrac{1 + \alpha^2}{\beta} = 1, \tag{19}$

and thus all have characteristic polynomial

$\chi_N(x) = x^2 + 1, \tag{20}$

we may affirm the the eigenvalues of any $N(\alpha, \beta)$ are $\pm i$, and the eigenvectors satisfy

$\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ -\dfrac{1 + \alpha^2}{\beta} & -\alpha \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} = \pm i\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}, \; v_1, v_2 \in \Bbb C; \tag{21}$

then with eigenvalue $i$,

$\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2 = i v_1, \tag{22}$

which since $\beta \ne 0$ yields

$v_2 = \dfrac{i - \alpha}{\beta} v_1; \tag{23}$

since eigenvectors are only determined up to a scaling factor, we can in fact take $v_1 = 1$ and then

$ \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\\dfrac{i - \alpha}{\beta}  \end{pmatrix}; \tag{24}$

since $N(\alpha, \beta)$ is a real matrix it follows that the eigenvector associated with $-i$ is

$\overline{ \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}} = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ \bar v_2 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\\dfrac{- i - \alpha}{\beta}  \end{pmatrix}; \tag{25}$

the diagonalizing matrix is thus

$V = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \dfrac{i - \alpha}{\beta} & \dfrac{-i - \alpha}{\beta} \end{bmatrix}, \tag{26}$

with

$\det(V) = -\dfrac{2i}{\beta}, \tag{27}$

we have

$V^{-1} =  \dfrac{\beta i}{2}\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{ -i -  \alpha}{\beta}   & -1 \\ -\dfrac{i - \alpha}{\beta} & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{ 1 - i\alpha}{2}  & -\dfrac{\beta i}{2} \\ -\dfrac{-1 - i\alpha}{2} & \dfrac{\beta i}{2} \end{bmatrix}; \tag{28}$

therefore

$V^{-1} N(\alpha, \beta)V = \begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{bmatrix}; \tag{29}$

finally, $N$ from (1) itself may be so represented *via* application of the above formulas; therefore *any* $N(\alpha, \beta)$ is similar to $N$, since each is similar to the diagonal matrix $\text{diag}(i, -i)$.

We have thus reached an affirmative answer to our OP Euler Pythagoras' closing question, even if our path has been a tad on the round-about side.  We did however discover the formula (15) for solutions to (1), which I think is pretty cool.

Comment: It is indeed pretty cool. I am impressed by the long answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something more general holds. If $f(t) = t^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1} + \dots + a_1t + a_0$ is a monic polynomial then the matrix

$$ C_f = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -a_0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -a_1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -a_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & -a_3 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is called the **companion matrix of $f$**. A simple calculation shows that $C_f$ *satisfies $f$*, meaning that
$$ f(C_f) = C_f^n + a_{n-1}C_f^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 C_f + a_0I = 0 $$

Moreover, if $C_f$ satisfies any other polynomial equation $g(C_f) = 0$ then $f$ divides $g$. We say that $f$ is the **minimal polynomial** of $C_f$.

There's a result in algebra called **rational normal form** (or "canonical form") that says that every matrix is similar to a block diagonal matrix of companion matrices. Specifically,

> If $A$ is a matrix that satisfies a polynomial $f$ (for example its characteristic polynomial) then $A$ is similar to a block diagonal matrix whose blocks are companion matrices. I.e. $$A \sim \operatorname{diag}(C_{g_1},\dots,C_{g_r}).$$
>   Moreover:
>
> 1. $g_i$ divides $f$ for $i = 1, \dots, r$
> 2. We can make it so that $g_i$ divides $g_{i + 1}$ for $i = 1,\dots,r-1$
> 3. If 2. holds, you can check that $g_r$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ in the sense described above.

One idea here is that if $h$ is any polynomial then
$$h(\operatorname{diag}(C_{g_1},\dots,C_{g_r})) = \operatorname{diag}(h(C_{g_1}),\dots,h(C_{g_r})). $$
This is true generally for block-diagonal matrices.

The point is that for the polynomial $f(t) = t^2 + 1$ the only real factors of $f$ are $1$ and $t^2 + 1$. On the other hand, $C_1$ is the empty $0\times 0$ matrix which just leaves us with $C_{t^2 + 1}$ is exactly what you called $N_0$.